# railsでdeviseを使って既存ルートにログインできるようにしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

rails7にてdeviseを使ってsign_upとsign_inのページを作りログイン後に指定パスにアクセスしたいのですが、実際にlocalhost:3000 users/sign_upからroot_pathに新規登録可能ですがなぜかsign_inするとページ遷移せずusers/sign_inに戻されてしまいます。

application.controller.rbにてparameterの設定やafter_sign_inの設定は使われているのになぜかsign_upで登録したものでsign_inをしてもページが切り替わりません。

もし同じような経験をしたことのある方がいましたら解決方法をご教授いただけないでしょうか?

対処法としてはapplication.controller.rbのパラメーターに:passwordや:usernameを加えたりしましたが、特に効果なくなぜかsign_upだけ正常にルートパスに遷移できています。

以下ソースコード

devise.rb

```
config.authentication_keys = [:name]
```

application.controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      root_path
    end
  
    protected
  
    
  
    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :email, :password])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in,keys:[:email, :password])
    end
end
```

seasons/new

```
<div class="mb-6 text-center">
  <span class="text-3xl font-bold">
    Sign In
  </span>
</div>

<div class='flex flex-wrap justify-center mb-6'>
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: root_path(resource_name), html: { class: "w-11/12 md:w-10/12 xl:w-8/12" }, data: { turbo: false } )  do |f| %>
    
    <div class="mb-6">
      <%= f.label :email, class: "mb-2 block text-sm text-gray-600" %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 py-2 px-3 placeholder:text-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-100" %>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-6">
      <%= f.label :password, class: "mb-2 block text-sm text-gray-600" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 py-2 px-3 placeholder:text-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-100" %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Sign In',  class: "inline-flex w-full items-center justify-center rounded-md bg-indigo-500 p-3 text-white duration-100 ease-in-out hover:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none cursor-pointer" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="text-center" >
<%= render "devise/shared/links"%>
</div>
```

registration/new

```
<div class="mb-6 text-center">
  <span class="text-3xl font-bold">
    Sign Up
  </span>
</div>

<div class='flex flex-wrap justify-center mb-6'>
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { class: "w-11/12 md:w-10/12 xl:w-8/12" }, data: { turbo: false } )  do |f| %>
    
    
    <div class="mb-6">
      <%= f.label :name, class: "mb-2 block text-sm text-gray-600" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 py-2 px-3 placeholder:text-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-100" %>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mb-6">
      <%= f.label :email, class: "mb-2 block text-sm text-gray-600" %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 py-2 px-3 placeholder:text-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-100" %>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mb-6">
      <%= f.label :password, "password", class: "mb-2 block text-sm text-gray-600" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 py-2 px-3 placeholder:text-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-100" %>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mb-6">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, class: "mb-2 block text-sm text-gray-600" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 py-2 px-3 placeholder:text-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-100" %>
    </div>
    
    <%= f.submit 'Sign Up', class: "inline-flex w-full items-center justify-center rounded-md bg-indigo-500 p-3 text-white duration-100 ease-in-out hover:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none cursor-pointer" %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="text-center">
  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

config/route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'home#home'
  devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
  resources :daily_workouts, only: %i[new create]

  
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Reveal health status on /up that returns 200 if the app boots with no exceptions, otherwise 500.
  # Can be used by load balancers and uptime monitors to verify that the app is live.
  get "up" => "rails/health#show", as: :rails_health_check

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "posts#index"
end
```